Паттерн создания и редактирования модели
Разрабатываю страничку сайта на dotnet + vue.js.
У меня есть список на странице. Можно добавлять и редактировать каждый элемент.
Я хочу, чтобы после создания элемента страница для создания меняла внешний вид на страницу редактирования без перезагрузки страницы. Модель и вёрстка у них практически одинаковая.
Но возникли сомнения, нормальный ли это подход? Вроде для пользователя - отличный, а с точки зрения архитектуры сайта - плохой, тк логика страниц создания и редактирования переплетается.
Понимаю, что все зависит от контекста задачи и нужно искать баланс, но может есть правильные шаблоны проектирования такого поведения?

Если модель одна, то через роутер vue меняй страницы... это же вполне типично/нормально когда разные компоненты рендерятся из одних и тех же данных.
